# Runtime permissions: onRequestPermissionsResult is getting called without prompting the user

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I am facing a very strange problem for the very first time. The problem is that I need some permissions at runtime. I am using the below code to get runtime permissions.

```
 private void askForPermissions() {
    if (!PermissionUtility.hasPermissions(this, mLoginViewModel.getPermissions())) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, mLoginViewModel.getPermissions(), LoginViewModel.CODE_PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
}
```

And this is where I intercept the user's grant or denial.

```
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == LoginViewModel.CODE_PERMISSION_ALL) {
        for (int a = 0; a < permissions.length; a++) {
            if (grantResults[a] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are mandatory to continue app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                askForPermissions();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the interesting thing. When I call `askForPermissions()`, it automatically calls `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. The key point is that no dialog is shown, so the user is not granting nor declining permissions. Why on earth `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is being called?

Below is the code of `onCreate()` where I am calling `askForPermissions()`.

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    askForPermissions();
}
```

Any help??

Comment: This can happen when the user denied the permission previously and chose "don't ask again" as part of that denial.

Comment: No user has not deined. I have just installed the application

Comment: Even uninstall the application not installed the app again samething happening

Comment: Make sure that you have the `<uses-permission>` elements matching `mLoginViewModel.getPermissions()` in the manifest in the correct location.